# Retrieving attachments from an email in an Outlook add-in?

Tags: outlook, add-in

How would I go about retrieving attachments from an email in a task pane add-in in Outlook? I want to upload the attachments of the email to an API endpoint of our own, but there does not seem to be any way to access the actual attachment contents from the office.js JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most compatible way to do this is by accessing the EWS (Exchange Web Services) API that will be running on most Exchange servers. In the Office.JS you can retrieve, the url of the EWS API, a token and the attachment ID of the attachments in your current email. Using this token and the attachments IDs you cna then retrieve the attachments programmatically. It is a bit of a hassle but it works reliably. More info on this can be found here: [enter link description here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/docs/outlook/get-attachments-of-an-outlook-item.md).